# Does Ruby on Rails support handle_asynchronously on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am trying out [Huginn](https://github.com/cantino/huginn) on Windows XP, and I have installed all the required components, but this code from `agent.rb` does not work:

```
    # The call that doesn't work
    Agent.async_receive(agent.id, agents_to_events[agent.id].uniq)

# ...

def async_receive(agent_id, event_ids)
   # See github...
end
handle_asynchronously :async_receive
```

If I inline the `async_receive` code it works fine, but if I view `/delayed_job` I see:

```
ID: 26
Priority: 10
Attempts: 0
Handler: --- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod
         object: !ruby/class 'Agent'
         method_name: :async_receive_without_delay
         args: [...]
```

I notice that the method name has become `:async_receive_without_delay`, but I don't know the significance of that.

**UPDATE**: I have further noticed that running `rake jobs:work` results in the above `async_receive` working correctly. Am I missing an initialisation somewhere?

Comment: what happens? Are you running delayed job ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I have the gem added, but perhaps I have missed an initialisation somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for jobs queued via `handle_asynchronously` or `delay` to get executed you need to run 1 or more instances of delayed job. There is more than one way to do this, one of them being

```
 rake jobs:work
```

Another is

```
ruby script/delayed_job start
```

You may wish to setup something like god to restart your delayed job workers should they stop.

Comment: I just came to a similar conclusion myself. I discovered the project's [schedule.rb](https://github.com/cantino/huginn/blob/master/bin/schedule.rb) which now moves my events into the `delayed_job` queue, so now if I have two DOS windows open with `bundle exec rails runner bin/schedule.rb` and `rake jobs:work` things work! Is there a better way to do this?